# How can I get comments template in single page of custom post type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created custom post type called blog & added some post to this post type.
But I am not able to see the comments template in single page of this custom post type.

I have also used `comments_template( '', true );`

But it shows nothing.

Comment: does <?php comments_template(); ?> return nothing on the template page?

Comment: @Rikesh yes it reside in the same folder.

Comment: @Joe I have also used <?php comments_template(); ?> and it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fire this SQL Query in your database

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'open' WHERE post_type = 'blog';
```

and don't forget to set tick mark in Settings -> Discussion Settings -> Allow people to post comments on new articles

in your admin panel
and click on save changes.

Answer (score 4):

you can also use the below queries as per your need

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status='open' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'blog';
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status='open' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'blog';
UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='open' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'blog';
UPDATE wp_posts SET ping_status='open' WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'blog';
```